# Reducing the Number of list properties in member class

Tags: c#, templating

i'm in the process of developing a template engine for specific internal files. I've currently got this code:

```
 public class properties
    {
        [DefaultValue("")]
        public string CompanyName { get; set;}
        [DefaultValue("")]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue("")]
        public string AddressExtra { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue("")]
        public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue("")]
        public string InvoiceDate { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue("")]
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue("")]
        public string Rep { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue("")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue("")]
        public string TaxRate { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue("")]
        public string Quantity1 { get; set; }
        public string Quantity2 { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

To coincide with this template: [image: Template]
  Being a some-what 'novice' to the C# development zone. I was wondering if it's possible to rething the implementation logic of a load of repeated attributes in the member class. Ie:

Quantity1, Quantity2, Quantity3,Quantity4 ... Right through to 14, and the same with all the other duplicated zones.

Having no idea how to reconsider this logic, I have turned to Stackoverflow for possible ideas (not external libraries. I want this to be a learning curve & self contained).

Comment: Are you familiar with [Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx) and [collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ybcx56wz.aspx)?

Comment: @alexw Arrays, yes. Collections, not so much. Will read over the links provided

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems pretty clear that you should have a "LineItem" class, something like:

```
public class LineItem
{
   public int Quantity {get; set;}
   public string Product {get; set;}
   public double UnitPrice {get; set;}
   public double TotalAmount {get; set;}
}
```

Your "Order" class (you called it "properties", not a good name for a class) would then hold a collection of these.

ie.

```
public class Order
{
   public string CompanyName {get; set;}
   ...
   public List<LineItem> Items {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Is that not essentially what is currently happening (despite a possible poor name) ? a self contained class to house the pre-set values on the template?

Comment: @DarylGill Well, mine doesn't have numbered variables. Your basic encapsulation wasn't too far off, you just needed to encapsulate the line items separately from the order itself.

Comment: I'm slowly following the logic behind the code. I'm still absolutely clueless about the numbered variables. How to implement seperate quantities, products, price and Unit price. But to be replaced on the right lines

Comment: @DarylGill Since each instance of `LineItem` is its own, well, instance (memory) you set them all up individually. Then you place each instance's data on its own line. Perhaps we should talk in chat?

Comment: If you do not mind. I think this might help alot with understanding, but only if your free enough. Otherwise, it's no trouble

Comment: @DarylGill http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61015/discussion-of-so-question-25776871

Comment: I'd like to again thank you for the time you spent with me. Have a +500 on me!

Comment: @DarylGill Thanks, thats very kind of you.